# Async in Railway Oriented Programming in F#

Tags: functional-programming, error-handling, asynchronous, f#, railway-oriented

In F# the [Railway Oriented Programming](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/rop/) pattern can be implemented synchronously using the `Result<'t,'terr>` type as result value for functions, so they can be foreward piped like:

```
let result = 
    func1
    |> Result.bind func2
    |> Result.bind func3
    |> Result.bind func4
```

I would like to implement the same pattern for functions returning `Async<Result<'t,'terr>>`, so I can pipe them like

```
let resultAsync = 
    func1Async
    |> Result.bindAsync func2Async
    |> Result.bindAsync func3Async
    |> Result.bindAsync func4Async
```

and execute that in a non blocking manner like

```
let result = resultAsync |> Async.RunSynchronously

match result with
| Ok(value) -> todoHandleOk values
| Error(msg) -> todoHandleError msg
```

To accomplish that I have implemented `Result.bindAsync` as an extension:

```
module Result = 
    let bindAsync<'t,'s,'terr> (binder:'t -> Async<Result<'s,'terr>>) (result:Async<Result<'t,'terr>>) : Async<Result<'s,'terr>> = 
        async {
            let! res = result
            match res with
            | Ok(value) -> return! binder value
            | Error(err) -> return Error(err)
        }
```

As shown it mimic the "normal" `bind` operation for a computational expression but encapsulated in a `async` workflow expression and hence returning an `Async<Result<'s,'terr>>`. The `result` argument is the Async "result" from the previous function which is executed to get its materialized result (`res`) before it can be used either as argument to the `binder` which is the next step on the successful track or returned as an error if unsuccessful.

---

**Test Case**

The below is a console test case with some functions that can be bound using `Result.bindAsync` as shown above.

```
module AsyncBindTests =

let anotherProcAsync = 
    async {
        for i in 1..Int32.MaxValue do
            printfn "Another Proc is at: %d" i
            do! Async.Sleep 800
    }

let rand = new Random();

let collectValuesAsync =
    async {
        printfn "Collecting Values..."
        let count = rand.Next(10, 15)
        let values = 
            List.init count (
                fun i -> 
                    async {
                        let x = rand.Next(1, 1000)
                        printfn "Value Collected: %d" x
                        do! Async.Sleep 500
                        return x
                    } |> Async.RunSynchronously
            )
        printfn "Values Collected"
        match (values |> List.sum) % 3 with
        | 0 -> return Error("Values sum is a multiple of 3")
        | _ -> return Ok(values)
    }

let groupValuesAsync values = 
    async {
        printfn "Grouping Values..."
        let sizeSum = 
            values 
            |> List.groupBy (fun v -> v % 3)
            |> List.sumBy (fun (k, lst) -> lst |> List.length)
        do! Async.Sleep 2000
        match sizeSum % 3 with
        | 0 -> return Error("Sum of Group Sizes is a multiple of 3")
        | _ -> return Ok (sizeSum, values)
    }

let crossSum value = 
    let rec cs v sum = 
        if v = 0 then sum
        else cs (v / 10) (sum + (v % 10))
    cs value 0

let getCrossSumAsync (sizeSum, values) =
    async {
        printfn "Checking Cross Sum..."
        let result = values |> List.fold (fun csum value -> csum + (crossSum value)) (crossSum sizeSum)
        do! Async.Sleep 2000
        match result % 3 with
        | 0 -> return Error "Crosssum is a multiple of 3"
        | _ -> return Ok(values)
    }

let runValuesFunctions = 
    collectValuesAsync
    |> Result.bindAsync groupValuesAsync
    |> Result.bindAsync getCrossSumAsync


let run () =
    printfn "AsyncBindTests"

    Async.Start anotherProcAsync
    let result = runValuesFunctions |> Async.RunSynchronously

    match result with
    | Ok(values) -> values |> List.iter (printfn "Value: %d")
    | Error(msg) -> printfn "ERROR: %s" msg

    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    Async.CancelDefaultToken()
```

---

Any feedback on the use of Async/async are welcome, but I'm especially interested in your thoughts about the Result.bindAsync. Am I violating something or are there better ways to do it?

Comment: This post has been [mentioned on Meta](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9205/9357).